# Django CMS auto display correct plugin for placeholder

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm a bit new to Django CMS (django-cms.org) as am having a difficult time finding a solution for this simple problem. In Django CMS, when I setup placeholders in a template, like so:

```
{% placeholder portfolio_image %}
{% placeholder portfolio_title %}
{% placeholder portfolio_link %}
{% placeholder portfolio_description %}
```

I can see each placeholder is displayed in an admin page, however, I need to select and add a plugin for each. I'd like portfolio_image to be set to an image, portfolio_title to a text plugin without a wysiwyg editor, portfolio_link to a link plugin, and portfolio_description to a text plugin. Is there a way to set this in the template? I don't want to see the dropdown to select and add a plugin.

For example:

```
{% image-placeholder portfolio_image %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to limit the type of plugins available to each placeholder by setting the [CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.3/getting_started/configuration.html?highlight=limiting%20placeholders#cms-placeholder-conf) setting.

Comment: Yes, I can limit the plugins, but you still need to manually select the plugin  from the dropdown. For example, If I limit a placeholder to 1 TextPlugin, you still need to select Text from the available plugins dropdown and then click add plugin. I'd like to have the text plugin already displaying without the need to select it from the dropdown.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd go about doing that. Perhaps you're better off just driving those areas from model instances.

Comment: So create a model instance for each template?

Comment: Perhaps. It's hard to say without seeing the design, use cases, etc.